# 正規表現の数字を外出し変数にして、正規表現の変数として利用したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

以下の例だと変数numberに4を入れても

```
import re

number = 4
print(fr"^\d{{number}}$") # 出力結果 1 ^\d{number}$
print(fr"^\d{4}$")        # 出力結果 2 ^\d4$
```

出力結果2のように正規表現として利用したいのですが、何か方法ございますでしょうか。
初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、何卒サポート頂けると幸いです。
タイトル含め、わかりにくい等ございましたらご指摘頂けると幸いです。

Comment: `print(fr"^\d{{{number}}}$")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[書式指定文字列の文法](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.8/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

> 波括弧を文字として扱う必要がある場合は、二重にすることでエスケープすることができます: {{ および }} 。

とあるとおり、以下のように記述すればよいです。

```
import re

number = 4

exp = rf'^\d{{{number}}}$'
print(exp) # ^\d{4}$

m = re.match(exp, '1234')
print(m) # <re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='1234'>
```

Comment: ありがとうございました！うまくいきました。今度はドキュメントを確認するようにいたします。